# Python removing all negative values in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the most efficient way to remove negative elements in an array? I have tried `numpy.delete` and [Remove all specific value from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032448/remove-all-specific-value-from-array) and code of the form `x[x != i]`.

For:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([-2, -1.4, -1.1, 0, 1.2, 2.2, 3.1, 4.4, 8.3, 9.9, 10, 14, 16.2])
```

I want to end up with an array:

```
[0, 1.2, 2.2, 3.1, 4.4, 8.3, 9.9, 10, 14, 16.2]
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
In [2]: x[x >= 0]
Out[2]: array([  0. ,   1.2,   2.2,   3.1,   4.4,   8.3,   9.9,  10. ,  14. ,  16.2])
```

Comment: what exactly would you call this operation? I'm interested in learning exactly how it works

Comment: its numpy.where (shortcut) and numpy slicing combined

Answer (score 6):

If performance is important, you could take advantage of the fact that your `np.array` is sorted and use [numpy.searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

For example:

```
In [8]: x[np.searchsorted(x, 0) :]
Out[8]: array([  0. ,   1.2,   2.2,   3.1,   4.4,   8.3,   9.9,  10. ,  14. ,  16.2])

In [9]: %timeit x[np.searchsorted(x, 0) :]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.47 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit x[x >= 0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.5 us per loop
```

The difference in performance will increase as the size of the array increases because `np.searchsorted` does a binary search that is O(log n) vs. O(n) linear search that `x >= 0` is doing.

```
In [11]: x = np.arange(-1000, 1000)

In [12]: %timeit x[np.searchsorted(x, 0) :]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit x[x >= 0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.87 us per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

In numpy:

```
b = array[array>=0]
```

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([-2, -1.4, -1.1, 0, 1.2, 2.2, 3.1, 4.4, 8.3, 9.9, 10, 14, 16.2])
>>> arr = arr[arr>=0]
>>> arr
array([  0. ,   1.2,   2.2,   3.1,   4.4,   8.3,   9.9,  10. ,  14. ,  16.2])
```

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a cool way to do this is numpy because numpy is magic to me, but:

```
x = np.array( [ num for num in x if num >= 0 ] )
```